# Running two methods in a partial class

Tags: c#

I have a method that does math and returns a value and another method right after that to return another value. The first method runs fine, but the second wont run at all. I have a feeling its due to the return from the first method. I am using a program called IX Developer. It allows c# scripting.

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
// Press F1 to get help about using script.
// To access an object that is not located in the current class, start the call with Globals.
// When using events and timers be cautious not to generate memoryleaks,
// please see the help for more information.
//---------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated
{
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools;
using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Graphics.Logic;
using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls;
using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Interfaces;

public partial class ConversionMath
{
    static ConversionMath()
    {
        Globals.Tags.Tank01_Product_Level_EU.Value = 177.66;
        Globals.Tags.Tank05_Product_Level_EU.Value = 377.66;
        Globals.Tags.Tank07_Product_Level_EU.Value = 147.66;
        Globals.Tags.Tank09_Product_Level_EU.Value = 257.66;
        Globals.Tags.Tank16_Product_Level_EU.Value = 67.66;
        Globals.Tags.Tank01_Total_Capacity.Value = 300;

        Globals.Tags.Tank01_Interface_Level_EU.Value = 8.66;
        Globals.Tags.Tank05_Interface_Level_EU.Value = 90.66;
        Globals.Tags.Tank01_Interface_Level_EU.Value = 142.66;
        Globals.Tags.Tank09_Interface_Level_EU.Value = 253.66;
        Globals.Tags.Tank16_Interface_Level_EU.Value = 64.66;

        Globals.Tags.Tank01_Product_Level_DISP.Value = 
            ConversionMath.LevelConverter(Globals.Tags.Tank01_Product_Level_EU.Value);
        Globals.Tags.Tank02_Product_Level_DISP.Value = 
            ConversionMath.LevelConverter(Globals.Tags.Tank02_Product_Level_EU.Value);

        //Interface Levels
        Globals.Tags.Tank01_Interface_Level_DISP.Value = 
            ConversionMath.LevelConverter(Globals.Tags.Tank01_Interface_Level_EU.Value);
        Globals.Tags.Tank02_Interface_Level_DISP.Value = 
            ConversionMath.LevelConverter(Globals.Tags.Tank02_Interface_Level_EU.Value);
    }

    public static string LevelConverter(float Product_Level_EU )
    {
        float fFT = Product_Level_EU / 12;
        int levelFT = (int)fFT;
        float levelIN = Product_Level_EU - levelFT * 12;
        string Product_Level_Disp = levelFT.ToString() + "'" + " " + levelIN.ToString() + '"';

        return Product_Level_Disp;
    }

    static PercentageAvailable()
    {   
        Globals.Tags.Tank01_Product_Level_EU.Value = 177.66;
        Globals.Tags.Tank01_Total_Capacity.Value = 300;

        Globals.Tags.Tank01_Avail_Vol.Value = ConversionMath.AvailPct(Globals.Tags.Tank01_Total_Capacity.Value, Globals.Tags.Tank01_Product_Level_EU.Value );
    }

    public static float AvailPct(float TotalCapacity, float Product_Level_EU)
    {
        float AvailPCT = (Product_Level_EU / TotalCapacity) * 100 ;
        return AvailPCT;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is the calling code?

Comment: and what exactly isn't working? "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.

Comment: I apologize, the first method runs fine and returns the value, the second does not. The code is continuously run it is not triggered by an event

Comment: Which function is the one you're having trouble with?  There's 3 functions there (+1 static constructor), of which only 2 will ever return anything.  Do you mean `AvailPct` or `LevelConverter`?

Comment: Specifically, what is the name of method 1 (the successful one) and method 2 (the failing one)?

Comment: The AvailPct method does not run

Comment: I believe the PercentageAvailable needs to be a static constructor as well.

Comment: I get an analog input from physical devices via modbus and scale them then display values on an interface device. The tags.value in the static constructor are simulated values to test the method with. The actual values are passed in from the device.

Comment: The DISP.Value is the tag value i display on the interface. When i have the PercentageAvailable as a static constructor and the AvailPct method in the ConversionMath class without ConversionMath constructor and LevelConverter method it will run. But if i have the two constructors and methods it says method (static PercentageAvailable() is supposed to be a constructor ) needs a return type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For The Responses. I got it figured out. i was trying to use a second constructor when i only needed the one. Here is what i ended up with.

```
   //--------------------------------------------------------------// Press F1 to get help about using script.// To access an object that is not located in the current class, start the call with Globals.// When using events and timers be cautious not to generate memoryleaks,// please see the help for more information.//---------------------------------------------------------------namespace Neo.ApplicationFramework.Generated{
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Tools;
using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Common.Graphics.Logic;
using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Controls;
using Neo.ApplicationFramework.Interfaces;
public partial class ConversionMath
{
static ConversionMath()

{   

Globals.Tags.Tank01_Product_Level_EU.Value = 177.66;
Globals.Tags.Tank05_Product_Level_EU.Value = 377.66;
Globals.Tags.Tank07_Product_Level_EU.Value = 147.66;
Globals.Tags.Tank09_Product_Level_EU.Value = 257.66;
Globals.Tags.Tank16_Product_Level_EU.Value = 67.66;
Globals.Tags.Tank01_Total_Capacity.Value = 300; 

Globals.Tags.Tank01_Interface_Level_EU.Value = 8.66;
Globals.Tags.Tank05_Interface_Level_EU.Value = 90.66;
Globals.Tags.Tank01_Interface_Level_EU.Value = 142.66;
Globals.Tags.Tank09_Interface_Level_EU.Value = 253.66;
Globals.Tags.Tank16_Interface_Level_EU.Value = 64.66;

Globals.Tags.Tank01_Product_Level_DISP.Value = ConversionMath.LevelConverter(Globals.Tags.Tank01_Product_Level_EU.Value);
Globals.Tags.Tank02_Product_Level_DISP.Value = ConversionMath.LevelConverter(Globals.Tags.Tank02_Product_Level_EU.Value);

//Interface Levels  
Globals.Tags.Tank01_Interface_Level_DISP.Value = ConversionMath.LevelConverter(Globals.Tags.Tank01_Interface_Level_EU.Value);
Globals.Tags.Tank02_Interface_Level_DISP.Value = ConversionMath.LevelConverter(Globals.Tags.Tank02_Interface_Level_EU.Value);

Globals.Tags.Tank01_Total_Capacity.Value = 300; 
Globals.Tags.Tank01_Avail_Vol.Value = ConversionMath.AvailPct(Globals.Tags.Tank01_Total_Capacity.Value, Globals.Tags.Tank01_Product_Level_EU.Value );

}   

public static string LevelConverter(float Product_Level_EU )
{
float fFT = Product_Level_EU / 12;
int levelFT = (int)fFT;
float levelIN = Product_Level_EU - levelFT * 12;
string Product_Level_Disp = levelFT.ToString() + "'" + " " + levelIN.ToString() + '"';
return Product_Level_Disp;
}
public static float AvailPct(float TotalCapacity, float TankVol)
{
float AvailPCT = (TankVol / TotalCapacity) * 100 ;  
return AvailPCT;
}   

}

}
```